# which exception should I use in getSingleResult

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA in my project

My method returns id of a table like the below

```
public Object getID(Long id)
    {

        String queryString="select id from test where testid= "+id;
        Query query = entityManagerUtil.entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
        return query.getSingleResult();


    }
```

So if there are no records then it will throw an error and then I will write the insert query in the catch block.

As I want to only insert when there are no recrds so I am confused which exception should I catch.

[oracle documnent](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult()) says `NoResultException` if there are no records but in my console I get `EmptyResultDataAccessException`

```
org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: No entity found for query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:294)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
```

So guys please tell me which exception should I catch if there are no records

Comment: Oracle document is for JPA. You're quoting some exception thrown by Spring JPA (not a JPA implementation) which presumably wraps the JPA exception. That's what you get from using wrapper libraries ... 2 sets of exceptions to be aware of

Comment: @NeilStockton are oracle JPA and Spring JPA both different?

Comment: different? JPA is a standardised SPEC for persistence (of which DataNucleus, EclipseLink and Hibernate are implementations), and Spring JPA imposes Springs own API on people rather than them using STANDARDISED JPA. Any basic Google search would reveal such things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an exists method and call the list method of `query`:

```
public boolean exists(Long id)

{

    String queryString="select id from test where testid= "+id;
    Query query = entityManagerUtil.entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
    if (query.list().size()>0){ 
       return true
    }

    return false
}
```

So you do not have to catch an exception.

Update :

You can also use the getId() function with `list`operation:

```
public Object getID(Long id)
    {

        String queryString="select id from test where testid= "+id;
        Query query = entityManagerUtil.entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);
        List l =  query.list().size();
        if (l>0){ 
          return l.get(0)
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks,getID() is used in some 50 other methods where I pass id.Now I use your way then I have to modify all the 50 methods to check if exists is true then call getID()

Comment: @SpringLearner: you can also combine my sollution and your getID() function. see my update.